# Как в Битрикс добавить модуль в меню

Tags: cms, битрикс

По инструкции

> http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/general/admin.section/rubric_admin.php

Создал файлы

> bitrix\modules\subscribe\admin\insert_admin.php
>
> bitrix\modules\subscribe\lang\ru\admin\insert_admin.php
>
> bitrix\bitrix\admin\insert_admin.php

В инструкции написано

> Теперь наш файл доступен по ссылке
>   http://mysite.ru/bitrix/admin/rubric_admin.php.

Собственно он и открывается по ссылке

> домен/bitrix/admin/insert_admin.php

А как его в меню то добавить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы добавить свой пункт меню в административном разделе, нужно зайти в админку - контент - файлы и папки. выбрать /bitrix/admin/. нажимаете "добавить" - "добавить меню". тип меню - "left". добавляете пункты, сохраняете.
новые пункты меню появятся в разделе "сервисы".

Comment: Что то не получается http://prntscr.com/8ealvd Нет такого пункта левое меню http://prntscr.com/8eam20

Comment: зайдите в настройки, настройки модулей - управление структурой. там будет список типов меню - создайте тип "left", назовите "меню раздела". после этого он появится в списках.

Comment: спасибо помогло